# Unable to start MySQL from XAMPP Control Panel

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am learning SQL with Udemy courses and I am currently doing a course called 'Learning database design using MySQL'.

I have downloaded XAMPP and the course video start MySQL directly from the XAMPP control panel. I however am not able to start MySQL via the control panel. This is the message i get:

*

```
20:56:08  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL app...
20:56:09  [mysql]   Status change detected: running
20:56:12  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
20:56:12  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
20:56:12  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
20:56:12  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
20:56:12  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
20:56:12  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
20:56:12  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
20:56:12  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
20:56:29  [mysql]   Problem detected!
20:56:29  [mysql]   Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini" MySQL57"!
20:56:29  [mysql]   MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
20:56:29  [mysql]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
20:56:29  [mysql]   or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
20:56:29  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL app...
20:56:30  [mysql]   Status change detected: running
20:56:33  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
20:56:33  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
20:56:33  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
20:56:33  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
20:56:33  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
20:56:33  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
20:56:33  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
20:56:33  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

*

I have logs that i can add if required. Also, i have downloaded sql community edition already and have used the command line functionality, however it is not running when trying to launch via the control panel.

I really want to learn so would really appreciate anyone who can help me overcome this issue.

Thanks
Graham

Comment: Do you have any other mysql  installed ? like wamp etc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are trying to start XAMPP (which comes with mysql) but already have MySQL Server 5.7 installed and running on your computer.

Comment: Evan, you are a legend! Learning can continue!

Answer (score 1):

First closed your `skype` then again start your `xamp`server as skype sometimes used port that is required for xamp

Next if xamp not started yet then go `config` into `httpd.conf` and search for `Listen 80` change your port to `81`
 and `httpd-ssl-conf` search `Listen 430` change to `4430`
 restart your xamp hope this can solve your problem

Comment: Hi Wasiq, thanks you for your reply. Would you be able to retype the second paragraph in a more 'idiot friendly' way? I'm not sure how to httpd.conf or the other one

Answer (score 0):

1.Open Xampp applications.
2.then Go to config. of Apache ->  Apache (httpd conf) -> Search Listen 80 It would be present at that start of the file.
3.Change it to Listen 82.
4.Then search ServerNamelocalhost:80
5.Change it to ServerNamelocalhost:82
6.then Go to config. of Apache ->  Apache (httpd-ssl- conf) -> Search Listen 442
7.change it to Listen 443

Restart your xampp

Hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

First you should install MySQL separately. Then go to the folder where you have installed xampp (default is c:). Go to phpMyAdim folder you will see config.inc.php file ,open it with any editor and put your MySQL password. Hopefully that'll work (by default its blank).

Answer (score 0):

this is work for me

```
01.Go to mysql/data/ directory
02. delete the ibdata1 & ib_logfile*(ib_logfile0,ib_logfile1,ib_logfile101) file
03. restart xampp server
```